# How to Query if Multiple Columns Reference to the Same Table

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I am facing an issue here. I have a table called application and it will record who requests the application, who approves it, and who rejects it. The issue is the Requestor_id, Approver_id and Rejector_id are references to the same table. How can I query for the requestor_name, approver_name, and rejector_name in Laravel

**Application table**

```
Requestor_id ( reference to user id)
Application_Status
Module_id
Approver_id ( reference to user id)
Rejector_id ( reference to user id)
created_at
updated_at
```

Below is what I have tried but it can only retrieve for the requestor name

```
$Approval_Logs = DB::table('application')
    ->select('application.id','application.Application_Status', 'users.name','application.Approver_id','application.Rejector_id', 'ems_application.Request_Category','application.updated_at')
    ->join('ems_application', 'ems_application.Application_id', '=', 'application.id')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'application.requestor_id')
    ->whereIn('application.Application_Status',['approved','rejected'])
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

I hope I can receive some hints from you. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did the proposed solution work for you?

Comment: @ggordon Yeah it did, Thank you! and sorry forgot to mark it as best answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use aliases in your joins also.

```php
$Approval_Logs = DB::table('application')
            ->select(
                 'application.id',
                 'application.Application_Status', 
                 
                 'application.Approver_id',
                 'approver.name as approver_name',
                 'application.requestor_id', 
                 'requestor.name as requestor_name',
                 
                 'application.Rejector_id', 
                 'rejector.name as rejector_name',


                 'ems_application.Request_Category',
                 'application.updated_at'
            )
            ->join('ems_application', 'ems_application.Application_id', '=', 'application.id')
            ->join('users as requestor', 'requestor.id', '=', 'application.requestor_id')
            ->join('users as approver', 'approver.id', '=', 'application.approver_id')
            ->join('users as rejector', 'rejector.id', '=', 'application.rejector_id')
            ->whereIn('application.Application_Status',['approved','rejected'])
            ->get()
            ->toArray();
```

I am not completely familiar with your application, however you may want to utilize `left_join` instead of `join` for the `approver` and `rejector` joins in the event that there was not an approver or rejector.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to do it the "Laravel" way. I would create a model called `Application` and create relations

```
class Application extends Model {

    public function requestor(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Users::class, 'requestor_id');
    }

    public function approver(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Users::class, 'approver_id');
    }

    public function rejector(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Users::class, 'rejector_id');
    }
}
```

Then in your controller, you can run the following query:

```
$application = Application::whereHas('requestor', function($query) {
                    $query->where('first_name', 'John');
               })->whereHas('approver', function($query) {
                    $query->where('first_name', 'Peter');
               })->whereHas('rejector', function($query) {
                    $query->where('first_name', 'Michael');
               })->get();
```

That should query the users table for the first names. I don't know how efficient this will be, but give it a try;